# TopoJSON data for all US Cities

Tags: javascript, mapping, geojson, topojson

I have been searching for a good data to project the US state and city boundaries in D3 (similar to the county/state boundary with all the famous examples.) I am looking for this to be able to map data I have on a city level.

Thus far, the best I have come up with is the data form the US census bureau data located here: http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2013/main (selecting places from the drop down menu.)

I downloaded all the individual files for every state and converted them to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr and then to TopoJSON using the topojson library. Here are the commands I used:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:4269 cities.geojson tl_2011_37_place.shp
topojson -s 7e-9 --id-property=+GEOID -o cities.json -- cities.geojson
```

I then used D3 to map, it but I don't get boarders...rather, it looks like the general shape is correct, but the border lines seem to have been cut/faded all over the place. Can someone help me point to what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

South Carolina:

Here is the code I am using to map the data:

```
    queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/shapefile/cities/cities.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "tsentiment.tsv", function(d) { countySentiment.set(d.id, +d.sentiment); })
    .await(ready);

/*
This function is used to initially draw of the US map with the initial data set
*/
function ready(error, cities) 
{

//setup your SVG
  svg = d3.select("#map_svg").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Draw the city lines
  svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "uscities")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(cities, cities.objects.cities).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);
}
```

Comment: You'll have better luck asking this question over at http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps you

```
var group = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(features)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

var areas = group.append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("fill", "#DCDCDC")
        .attr("stroke", "#FFFFFF");
```